# How to limit search parameters in Firebase?

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have linked my Android application to a Firebase Database, the problem is that every time I search for a name in the database, it shows all the database.

How do can I make the application only show the single names? Here's how it's seen:

[image: here's how it's seen]

This is the controller code that gets the database:

```
.controller('BirreCtrl', function($firebaseObject){
  const rootRef=firebase.database().ref().child('databaseBirre');
  this.object=$firebaseObject(rootRef);
})
```

And this one is its HTML code in the search page:

```
<li ng-show="search" ng-controller="BirreCtrl as birra" ng-animate="animate"><i class="icon ion-beer" id="icona_birra"></i> {{ birra.object | json}}</li>
```

Comment: What do want to fetch exactly , right now you are fetching databaseBirre , Its , just inside your firbase database . Are there data inside of it too ?

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: here's the database structure that came out from the exporting JSON:


{
  "databaseBirre" : {
    "Barley" : "4/10",
    "Old English 800" : "3/10"
  }
}

Comment: Not sure what you need , but if you need data inside Barley , you should use firebase.database().ref('databaseBirre').child('Barley');

Answer (score 0):

Right now data you are getting is synchronized object is created with several special $ properties like $id etc. If You want data value you should be doing like this

```
  var data = $firebaseObject(ref.child('databaseBirre'));
  data.$loaded().then(function () {
  console.log(data);
  }
```

**OR**

```
  var ref = new Firebase('<your-firebase>');
  var data = $firebase(ref).$asArray();
  console.log(data);
```

Hope this help you out .  Thanks :)

Comment: it works, but it only shows the value (vote) on the console of a single beer.

what i need is that the database retrieve the beer names, not the value.

something like a list like this:
Barley
Heineken
etc..

the problem is that the beer name is the name, while the vote it's a value, but in seems that there no variable called $name, maybe i'm doing something wrong, maybe i structured the database badly?

Comment: actually this is your whole firebase database object, Are you sure there are more than what you are getting now ?

Comment: sorry, i wrote the comment incomplete for error, now i edited it.

Comment: can you check console for my updated answer ? What is the output ?

Comment: it says "undefined", could it be that there are more than one value, should it be an array?

Comment: well .. its quite a pickle isn't it :D another update

Comment: is it normal that it says that obj.$asArray() is not a function?

Comment: Nope i dont think so .. it means your array is not sync anyway .. a new and last update for today from my side . hope it work (Y)